# Vertically align LaTeX preview in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I would like to vertically align org mode latex previews at the same level than the surrounding text, that is I want the bottom of the surrounding text to be at the same level than the bottom of the preview. Is that possible?

The following screenshot shows the default behavior which is to align the center of the image with the top (or center?) of the surrounding text:

[image: LaTeX preview in Org Mode]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I didn't really understood what org mode is, but found out that has to do with emacs. Thus, I suppose that the page https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ will give you more possibilities to get an answer. If I am wrong and your question is more relevant with LaTeX than with emacs, please ask me to delete this comment

Comment: Just use org-mode with [`texfrag-mode`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) as minor mode. It replaces the org mode latex stuff with that one of `preview.el` which works way better.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up advicing an internal function since there is no clean extension hook nor customization option for this:

```
(defun my-org-latex-preview-advice (beg end &rest _args)
    (let* ((ov (car (overlays-in beg end)))
           (img (cdr (overlay-get ov 'display)))
           (new-img (plist-put img :ascent 90)))
      (overlay-put ov 'display (cons 'image new-img))))
(advice-add #'org--format-latex-make-overlay
            :after #'my-org-latex-preview-advice)
```

No quite nice but it does the work.